# For loop after pandas groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, group-by

My input dataframe looks like:

```
name   uniqueID
kate   0001
sam    0001
lucy   0002
wes    0001
kip    0002
```

I have the following:

```
addData =pd.read_csv('/input.csv')
grouped = addData.groupby(['uniqueID'])
filename = addData['uniqueID'][0]
output_csv = '/test/output_{}.csv'.format(filename)

for name, group in grouped:
    group.to_csv(output_csv)
```

My output is semi-correct. I have a file with all the associated records for that `'uniqueID'`, EX) `output001.csv`:

```
name   uniqueID
kate   0001
sam    0001
wes    0001
```

The problem is that I am only getting **one file** - my loop is not working correctly to produce both `output0001.csv` and `output0002.csv`

Comment: groupby and to csv

Comment: do: `group.to_csv('/test/output_{}.csv'.format(group['uniqueID'][0]))`

Comment: `addData['uniqueID'][0]` will only ever be a single value, `0001`. Therefore `output_csv` will only ever be that value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
grouped = addData.groupby(['uniqueID'])
filename = addData['uniqueID'][0]
output_csv = 'output_{}.csv'

for name, group in grouped:
    group.to_csv(output_csv.format(name))
```